# How to add a block below products list of perticular category in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.7, php

I want to add one block for product lines below the products list. When I select a perticular product I want to add Product name as well as its price in the product lines block.

Also I will select multiple products from products list and the lines will be added in the block one by one.

Comment: @JNDPNT: I know my question is not so good, But i am very new to magento development and I don't know how to start with the above problem.

Comment: @Tim for example selected products are as below:
        `PC       $39 x 1  =     $39`
 `Keyboard    $19 x 1  =     $19`
 `Mouse       $19 x 1  =     $19`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new template file where you load the products and display info
2. Add the template file in the catalog.xml (or local.xml) under the list.
3. create a handle to do ajax-requests (dynamically updating the product-lines block)
4. create controller to save product line and return block
5. update block content using the ajax handle and controller

That's roughly what it takes if I'm not missing something. I would not recommand this as a newbie to magento, learn the basics first, this is not easy ;-).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can u tell me how much time i will require to do this?

Comment: Depends on your knowledge of magento. I really can't tell :-). Definitely shorter if you don't have to save the data and you can just add the info using javascript. Than no block, controller, ... is needed and you just append with javascript :-).

Comment: And one last question can I create a new module for this?

Comment: YES YOU CAN :P (but that requires also knowledge of magento)

Comment: Yes have created some sample modules in Magento. So I think it will not take much time to me to understand. By the way thanks for help. I will ask you for further help if I stuck somewhere. :)

Comment: I am getting problem in 2nd point (add template file under list). I am not able to see the template added under list file in my magento.